# Variável não definida em for-loop em Python

Tags: python, loop, for, declaração-de-variável

Estou com um problema em um código que deveria ler 4 valores usando `raw.input().split()` e depois um `for-loop` para transformar tais valores em  `float`. O interpretador me retorna:

> "name 'val' is not defined"

Segue o código:

```
p=raw.input().split()
for i in range (0,4)
    val[i]=float(p[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas. Conforme o erro auto-descritivo apresentado pelo compilador falta declarar a lista `val` antes de usá-la.

Talvez seja só questão de versão, mas usei a função `input()` para executar corretamente.

Faltou o `:` no fim da linha do `for`.

Isso só funciona em circunstância bem específicas, o que não é um problema para um exercício, mas seria em aplicação real. Ainda não é a melhor forma de fazer mas assim funciona:

```
val = []
p = input('Digite uma sequência de números ').split()
for i in range(0, 4):
    val.append(float(p[i]))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SjNB95). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ibohsdrx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/FillListByString.py).

Comment: Havia esquecido que o equivalente de vetores em python são listas. Valeu pela ajuda fera!