# Como eu faço para os input ficarem na mesma linha?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria que quando alguém for dar a entrada, os input ficassem na mesma linha, já tentei usar o comando 'split', mas não consegui.

```
D = int(input())
R = int(input())
L = int(input())
P = int(input())
G = int(input())
autonomia = L * 10
km = (D - autonomia) / 10
gas = km * G
distancia = D // (P + 1)
if D <= autonomia:
   print('Pode viajar\nR$: {}'.format(int(R - gas)))
elif D >= distancia and R >= gas:
   print('Pode viajar\nR$: {}'.format(int(R - gas)))
elif D >= autonomia or distancia and gas > R:
   print('Não pode viajar')
```

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427259/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346650/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149149/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454645/101 ou uma 50 que já tem no site sobre isso. Não sei se em alguém está escrito que isso não é uma boa ideia, mas deveria. Não sei porque trocar o simples pelo complicado.

Comment: É simples, uma questão no The Huxley quer assim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o map, split e atribuições multiplas. Como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```
D, R, L, P, G = map(int, input().split())
```

Split:

> é um método que retorna uma lista a partir de uma string.

Map:

> executa uma função especificada para cada item em um iterável. O item
> é enviado para a função como parâmetro.

A atribuição múltipla nesse caso é limitado em 5, pois é o número de variáveis que passamos ao lado esquerdo do =.

Comment: Legal! Mas por que isso funciona? Poderia explicar com um pouco mais de detalhes? Saiba mais sobre como elaborar uma boa e bem explicada resposta **[aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8478/69296)**.

Comment: Funciona pois o split vai 'criar' uma lista com as entradas separados por espaço. Depois o map vai aplicar a esse iterável(a lista criada pelo split)  e ira converter em inteiro.

Comment: Acho que também vale explicar sobre a atribuição múltipla, e o fato de que neste caso a entrada deve ter exatamente 5 números para funcionar